# How can I get back the "natural" order in the Buffer List?

Tags: emacs

With <kbd>C-x C-b</kbd> the buffer list is displayed.  First in it's natural order with most recently used buffers on top, and buried buffers at the bottom.

There, I can now sort the Buffer by name, size, mode and file. But once I click on such an option I cannot go back to the original ordering.

Also killing the buffer and recreating it does not change that order.  (Using 25.2)

So how can I get that ordering back without restarting emacs?

Comment: You might want to investigate `ibuffer-mode` as a replacement for the standard buffer list. See [the EmacsWiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IbufferMode) for details. In `ibuffer-mode`, you can sort by recency with `s v`.

Comment: @NickD: Thank you! This is the answer. Please put it as an answer!

Comment: OK - done. I tried to cover the basics; let me know if you think I should add more detail (or feel free to add it yourself).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another mode that's nowadays built-in to Emacs that can be used to display the buffer list: [ibuffer-mode](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IbufferMode).

If you are not using it already, you can experiment with `M-x ibuffer` and find out its capabilities with `C-h m`. Note that in particular, it can sort the buffer list in various ways, one of which is by `recency` with `s v`, which is what the OP asked for; but note also that it has many other ways to sort that make it very flexible.

Once you are convinced that that's the way to go, you can redefine the `C-x C-b` keybinding in your init file with:

```el
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-b") 'ibuffer)
```

I did that a long time ago and have never looked back. IMO, it should be the default: that may come to pass, but AFAIK that is still not the case.

Comment: Thanks for the bounty! That was unexpected.

Answer (score 1):

Sorting order goes away as expected when I kill buffer named `*Buffer List*` and reopen using C-x C-b (Using emacs 27.1 & 28.1). From the [EmacsWiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BufferMenuSorting)

> Once sorted, there is no nice way to restore the default MRU sort. You
> have to ‘kill-buffer’ the buffer menu buffer, and then re-open it.
> (Sorting sets the variable ‘tabulated-list-sort-key’ in
> tabulated-list.el. Its default is ‘nil’. No way to restore the nil
> value is provided.)

May be worth adding a custom function which can disable the sort **without closing the buffer**.

```
(defun disable-buffer-sort()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (set-buffer (get-buffer "*Buffer List*"))
    (setq tabulated-list-sort-key 'nil)
    (revert-buffer)
    ))

(disable-buffer-sort)
```

As @NickD mentioned in other answer `ibuffer-mode` is also a good alternative with more features.